# MySQL limits decimals in round() to fewer than expected

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, percona

I have two different MySQL servers, when i run the following query on both, i get different results:

```sql
SELECT round(1/3,6) -- 0,333333 on Server1
SELECT round(1/3,6) -- 0,3333   on Server2
```

The first one gives 6 decimals as expected, the second one gives only 4 decimals.

```sql
SELECT format(round(1/3,6),6) -- 0,333333 on Server1
SELECT format(round(1/3,6),6) -- 0,333300 on Server2

SELECT round(cast(1 as float)/3,6) -- 0,333333 (6 decimals) on both

SELECT 1/3 -- 0,3333 (4 decimals) on both as expected
```

The MySQL Version is 8.0.18-9 on Server1 and 8.0.26-17 on Server2.
div_precision_increment = 4 on both servers.

**UPDATE:**

Its a mysql version issue - when updated to 8.0.26 both servers have the same issue. But i think its the behaviour of 8.0.26 thats buggy.

In 8.0.27 there is a bugfix description that might address this issue:

> Type resolution for negation did not set the proper precision when converting the type from integer to decimal. This is fixed by assigning the same precision as the argument. (Bug #32863037)

But Percona does not offer that update for now, so ill try to downgrade and then wait for 8.0.27+

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE:

This is a error in the version, update the version of the 8.0.18 server to the same version

it is a server variable

```
SET div_precision_increment = 6;
```

> will change for the session the number of digits.
> This variable indicates the number of digits by which to increase the scale of the result of division operations performed with the / operator. The default value is 4. The minimum and maximum values are 0 and 30, respectively. The following example illustrates the effect of increasing the default value.

[more information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment)

Comment: Thx, this seems to be only a part of the problem. div_precision_increment is set to 4 on both servers, so this does not explain the different results. However when i set it to 6 i get the 6 decimals, but then i have the same issue when i use any lager number of decimals.

Comment: you can write a function to set the precision for the result, or CAST abc AS DECIAML, but usulally yyou  have a fiexed division per project. if you need it flexible use a function

Comment: Well i have a project with thousands of queries that worked fine till some time ago, some update or setting seems to have changed the behaviour - the question is why does it work in a flexible way on Server1 but not (anymore) on Server2?

Comment: Ok its a mysql version issue - when updated to 8.0.26 both servers have the same issue. But i think its the behaviour of 8.0.26 thats buggy. In 8.0.27 there is a bugfix description that might address this issue "Type resolution for negation did not set the proper precision when converting the type from integer to decimal. This is fixed by assigning the same precision as the argument. (Bug #32863037)". But Percona does not offer that update for now, so ill try to downgrade.